# Why changing core size limit changes the location of coredump?

Tags: centos, core-dump

I am experiencing a weird behavior on CentOS 7.1. I have enabled saving the coredump by setting the following values

- OpenGPGCheck = no
- ProcessUnpackaged = yes

in  `abrt-action-save-package-data.conf`. If I now run my app that causes the coredump the coredump is saved in `/var/tmp/abrt/ccpp-timestamp/coredump`.

I then noticed that for some reason after a few coredumps old coredumps are overwritten by the new coredumps. So I decided to set the core limit to `unlimited` by adding

```
myUserName       soft      core      unlimited
```

in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

But what I noticed is that adding this line causes the coredump to be saved in the directory where I have my application running.

I have not modified any other file, like `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` or `sysctl.conf`.

I'd like to know why the location of the coredump is changed.